# scipy.interpolate.griddata not working as expected

Tags: python, scipy, grid, interpolation

I have a large dataset of temperatures throughout the US on a grid of 3km-3km:

[image: Temps of the USA]

The temps (`temperature_data`), latitudes and longitudes of each grid point are available where the lat/lon data are `lats` and `lons`, all with shape (1060,1800).

I also have a sub-regional high-resolution dataset I would like to extrapolate the `temperatures_data` from at each grid point. I have the latitudes and longitudes of these locations as `rlats` and `rlons`, each with shape (720,3840).

Reading around, I found the `scipy.interpolate.griddata` function, and used it as the following:

```
highres_temps = griddata((lats.flatten(),lons.flatten()),temperature_data.flatten(),(rlons,rlats),'nearest')
```

The results give me in the new grid all have the same value:

```
print(np.amax(highres_temps))
print(np.amin(highres_temps))
28.175049
28.175049
```

And if we zoom into the area of interest of `highres_temps`:

[image: zoomedin_highres_temps]

And zoom into the area of interest of `temperature_data`:

[image: zoomedin_temperature_data]

It is obvious the temps in `temperature_data` do not match with what should be extracted over the domain within `rlats` and `rlons`. Why might this be occurring?

Comment: rlats and rlons were switched in my griddata command..

Comment: Will be difficult to reproduce unless you include more of your code and link your data. Is that possible?